# encoding in sqlite manger(firefox plugin) and sqlites

Tags: firefox, python-3.x, encoding, sqlite

I  found a interested thing，my sqlite encoding is utf-8, my coding page is 936,and i installed sqlite manager (firefox plugin).
case1:

```
import sqlite3  
conn = sqlite3.connect('g:\\testdb.s3db')  
conn.text_factory = str  
c = conn.cursor()  
c.execute('create table if not exists test(name text)')  
name = '测试'.encode('utf-8')     
t = (name,)  
c.execute('insert into test values (?)', t)  
conn.commit()
```

1)in sqlite3 console,i can `select * from test`,get '测试' properly displayed.
2)when i open it in sqlite manager,i get unreadable code.
it is the utf-8 of '测试'  'xE6B58BE8AF95'

case2:

```
import sqlite3  
conn = sqlite3.connect('g:\\testdb.s3db')  
conn.text_factory = str  
c = conn.cursor()  
c.execute('create table if not exists test(name text)')  
name = '测试'   
t = (name,)  
c.execute('insert into test values (?)', t)  
conn.commit()
```

1)in sqlite3 console,i can `select * from test`,get '测试' properly displayed.
2)when i open it in sqlite manager,get '测试' properly displayed.

now ,i guess:
1.when select * from sqlite to display in the sqlite3 console,
case 1:  name = '测试'.encode('utf-8')  , coding page is 936, transformed into gbk to be displayed.
case 2:  name = '测试'  ,the word '测试' is unicode , transformed into gbk to be displayed.

2.sqlite manager use unicode as default encoding to work with?in case 2,the unicode coding point were writed into sqlite
db,am i right?

3.in my opinion it is better to write name = '测试'.encode('utf-8')  than  name = '测试' ,our target is to store utf-8  encoding of strings, not unicode.

4.in my firefox ,encoding is unicode,it is code point? but code point is not a encoding.

Comment: Are you using Windows?

Comment: yes ,win7+python3.3+firefox+sqlite manager

Comment: The Windows Command Prompt does not handle UTF-8 correctly. Do not use it to enter or show UTF-8 data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a string as the parameter. The SQL statement encodes the string as UTF-8 and binds it as `TEXT` by calling [`sqlite3_bind_text`](https://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/bind_blob.html). If you instead use encoded `bytes` as the parameter, it gets bound as a sqlite3 `BLOB` by calling `sqlite3_bind_blob`. When you fetch the values, sqlite3 decodes `TEXT` as UTF-8 and returns a `BLOB` as `bytes`:

```
import sqlite3
conn = sqlite3.connect(':memory:')
c = conn.cursor()
c.execute('create table test(name text)')
c.execute('insert into test values (?)', ('测试',))
c.execute('insert into test values (?)', ('测试'.encode(),))

>>> c.execute('select * from test').fetchall()
[('测试',), (b'\xe6\xb5\x8b\xe8\xaf\x95',)]
```

As to the Windows console, a CPython `io.FileIO` object always reads and writes `bytes` using POSIX `read` and `write`, which are implemented in the C runtime on Windows. CPython doesn't support Microsoft's text-mode flags, such as `_O_U16TEXT`, which select the wide-character console API and require a `wchar_t` buffer. As such, printing to the console in python.exe is limited to the ANSI codepage. This is set as `sys.stdout.encoding` when the interpreter is initialized.

Codepage 65001 (`CP_UTF8`) is broken but can be fixed for printing by running ANSICON with the environment variable setting `ANSICON_API=python`. This hooks `WriteFile` with a function that instead calls [`MyWriteConsoleA`](https://github.com/adoxa/ansicon/blob/v1.66/ANSI.c#L1559) when the file handle is a console.

Comment: and the problem about firefox encoding?

Comment: Does view----encoding----unicode in firefox mean utf-8?I don't think so.

Comment: if view----encoding----unicode in firefox means utf-8 ,why name = '测试'.encode('utf-8')   written into db can't be displayed .

Comment: Case 1 inserts a `BLOB`. Case 2 inserts `TEXT`. The Firefox plugin output is consistent with this. Your Python modules should use UTF-8, the default source encoding for Python 3. The string literal `"测试"` will be saved in the file as the bytes `"\xe6\xb5\x8b\xe8\xaf\x95"`. Similarly, the console encoding set on `sys.stdin.encoding` is used for decoding a string literal from stdin. For GBK, it reads the bytes `"\xb2\xe2\xca\xd4"`.

Comment: Perhaps you don't know that the `X` prefix for a string of hex digits, e.g. `X'E6B58BE8AF95'`, is the [literal representation](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_expr.html#litvalue) of a `BLOB`. Otherwise, what else can I add to help?